# Can Windows Services with Admin User Account to start msiexec updating app for update an app

Tags: windows-services, updates, windows-installer

Like in the title, I liked to know, please, if any admin user account windows service can to start and to run (with success, that is, without failures!) an updating, msiexec based, app for updating another app installed with a msi package.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the right circumstances (signed MSI and MSP patch files) you don't even need to be admin to install a patch update, a non-admin can do it:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa372388(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Yes, this is a very good technique, we use it very intensively. But it comes not without effort (managing certificates, especially certificates, it is good practice to have them renewed every 1-2 years normally (depends on yours, of course), and then this certificate update has to be installed with admin rights again, before you can create new patches which can be installed without admin rights.   --  You have to think, if writing (or buying) an update service / tool is not more convenient- because this can also update full MSI setups and not only patches without admin login / UAC .

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, if I understand you correct: Yes, any elevated (either with localsystem or with admin rights) Windows service let' call it *A*, can start an application *B* which has "enough" rights to update every MSI based application *C*.

You have not to bother about right inheritance: The rights are cleanly inherited, even further, so *B* can start also *D*, which starts *E*, and *E* can update you MSI (-based *C*).

To be clear, what is **not** ("normally" and easily) possible, that the .MSI setup of C starts the MSI setup of another application, let's call them *F*.
Normally only one MSI can run at one time.
(Disclaimer: Of course it is not completely impossible, but not a best-practice nowadays, and if, should be done only by real MSI experts).

If you want to update multiple MSIs, recommended way is, that *B* updates first the *C* MSI and then maybe others like *F*.

Remark: Normally you don't need three levels, two are enough- one .exe and one .msi are best recommendation: Starting first an .exe (either service or normal application) with elevated rights (e.g. a setup.exe, called also a 'bootstrapper' for the MSI), and let this call the MSI file, ist most recommended way to avoid possible annoying or suprising effects especially for non-MSI experts.
This compared to the doubleclick on the .msi file itself and relying on UAC which comes quite late which has effects.